# Why does stripe create successive payments after checkout?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I'm new to stripe and I'm trying to update the checkout of an existing website to the new version of stripe. After some hardship I've been (almost) successful but now I see that something in my code is making stripe make several subscriptions (like several per minute) after I checkout. How can I stop this?

My code:

```
app.post('/create-checkout-session', async (req, res) => {
    // let priceId = Object.keys(req.body);
    // let objId = new ObjectId(req.body.sub_id);
    // let norma = new ObjectId(req.body.norma);
    // let rsa = new ObjectId(req.body.rsa);

    // Subscription.find({_id : objId},{"_id": 0,"stripePlanId":1})
    //     .then((result) => {
    //         console.log(result);
    //     })
    //     .catch((err) =>
    //         console.log(err));

    userId = req.user._id;

    let planId;
    let planRenewal;
    let normPlanId, rsaPlanId;
    let planName;
    let cartElements = [];

    customer = await stripe.customers.create({
        description: req.user.name,
        address : {
            country: 'PT',
        }
    });
    
    await Subscription.find({_id: req.body.sub_id})
        .then((result) => {
            planId = result[0].stripePlanId;
            planRenewal = result[0].renewalPeriod;
            planName = result[0].name;
        })
        .catch((err) =>
            console.log(err));

    cartElements.push(planId);

  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    line_items: cartArray,
    mode: 'subscription',
    customer: customer.id,
    success_url: `${process.env.web_app_url}/subscricoes`,
    cancel_url: `${process.env.web_app_url}`,
    automatic_tax: {enabled: true},
  });

  res.redirect(303, session.url);
});

app.post('/webhook', express.raw({ type: 'application/json' }), async (req, res) => {
    let event;

    // try {
        event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(req.body, req.header('stripe-signature'), endpointSecret);
    // } catch (err) {
    //     console.log(err);
    //     return res.sendStatus(400)
    // }

    if (event.type === 'payment_intent.succeeded') {
        const data = event.data.object;
        
        const paymentMethod = event.data.object.payment_method;
        // const customer = event.data.object.customer;

        // attach payment to customer
        const attachPaymentToCustomer = await stripe.paymentMethods.attach(
            paymentMethod,  // <-- your payment method ID collected via Stripe.js
        { customer: customer.id } // <-- your customer id from the request body  
        );

        //create subscription
        const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create({
            customer: customer.id,
            items: [{ plan: 'plan_DznNb3tPEEI0cj' }],
            default_payment_method: paymentMethod,
            expand: ['latest_invoice.payment_intent']
        });
       
        await User.updateOne(
            {_id: ObjectId(userId) },
            {$set: { "stripeCustomer": customer}},
        );

        await User.updateOne(
            {_id: ObjectId(userId) },
            {$set: { "stripeCustomer.subscriptions": subscription}},
        );
    }

    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a Checkout Session in subscription mode, the payment method will be attached to the customer and the Subscription will be created. Which is why you don’t need to handle any of this in the webhook endpoint.

To make it clear, what’s happening here is that you’re webhook endpoint code is listening to the `payment_intent.succeeded` event, which will occur when the Checkout Session has been paid, and then you’re creating a new subscription to the same customer which will subsequently result in another `payment_intent.succeeded`  event and so on.

I would suggest removing this part of the webhook endpoint code and following this guide https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders#fulfill to handle the fulfillment of the Checkout Session after it was completed.

Comment: That solved it! Thanks!